# Generating random 3 dates in the range taken from the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
Table_1
         |id| date       |
         | 1| 2012-01-01 |
         | 2| 2012-01-08 |
         | 3| 2012-01-15 |
         | 4| 2012-01-22 |
```

My table is much larger than this and it also has a 7 day period :

- I need to randomize 3 dates between id1 and id2
- 3 dates between id3 and id4
- And so on
- "Why not between 2 and 3?" Because id1 is the beginning of the week
  and id 2 is the end of the week, I need 3 random dates from the week

Comment: your question needs improvement, which language are you using? wich database? you need to explain exactly what you want to do, but i think you can find easily how to do this just googling

Comment: Why not between 2 and 3? what if there are odd number of rows?